# Website, tool or app to produce colored map of the United States?

Tags: maps, color

Does anyone know of a website, Windows program or iOS app that has a clickable map of the United States and colors in the states that are clicked on? Looking to produce a map of states I have visited or lived in. Ideally it would be nice to be able to save and print this image as well. Thanks.

Comment: A world version with US States included - http://www.travbuddy.com/world-travel-map

Comment: US Version - http://www.ammap.com/visited_states/

Answer (score 3):

**A World version with US States included**

http://www.travbuddy.com/world-travel-map

**US Version only**

http://www.ammap.com/visited_states/

(Embeddable for both)

Answer (score 1):

Another great app for your purpose is  **MakeaClickableMap**

http://www.makeaclickablemap.com

It has many options to color states, assign URLs to them, show/hide map labels, show text box on mouse over etc.

Disclosure: I wrote it. :)